# I can't boot from USB in grub

Tags: boot, usb

I'm new to using Linux and I tried googling an answer but I didn't understand the instructions. I installed Lubuntu but I must've messed up somewhere because my computer goes directly to GRUB.

After pressing tab and trying a bunch of commands, I was finally about to load the BIOS thing in order to have it boot USB first. For some reason, I can't boot the USB and nothing happens when I click F12 and choose SanDisk from the boot menu. The ISO is for CloudReady if that helps. I read online about booting from within GRUB but it tells me I have to do something with the kernel first. I think the file is startup.nsh since that's the only file I could find while checking each hd. It would be much appreciated if someone could help me with easy instructions since I've searched for hours and tried everything I could find but I didn't understand how to do it properly.

Sorry if I wasn't clear so I'll try to list what I did.

- I have an old Gateway computer sx2110g with Windows 10 installed. Windows was slow so I wanted to try a version of Linux.
- I tried installing Lubuntu but I must've messed up because my computer only boots in GRUB.
- After looking online i found that typing `fwsetup` on Grub let's me restart into the BIOS.
- I wanted to install a different OS so I set "removable device" to boot first.
- When I restart it only says "*boot loader not found*" then immediately goes to Grub.
- I tried f12 to manually choose the USB drive but the same thing happens and it immediately goes to Grub.

My question is that if there's a way to boot a USB from within Grub since that's the only thing that's opening for me on the computer. I tried these instructions:
https://szymonkrajewski.pl/how-to-boot-system-from-usb-using-grub/
I was able to figure out which drive is the USB by typing "ls" and searching each drive but I don't know how to boot `startup.nsh`.

Comment: `startup.nsh` would be a start-up script for a UEFI shell. It should not have anything to do with booting Linux unless your set-up is very special. Please edit your question to add as much hard facts as you can: the make and model of your system, the exact messages you're seeing from GRUB, and URLs to instructions you have tried to follow so far. "It tells me I have to do something with the kernel first" sounds like one of the previous commands you've tried has failed, and you're trying to keep going regardless; that won't work.

Comment: have you tried booting the stick on a different computer? can you boot your computer with a lubuntu-stick? I am pretty sure that the problem is your cloudReady-Stick and not you bios/current installation

Answer (score 0):

To boot UEFI-style from a removable device, that removable device should have a partition that is readable to the UEFI firmware (all UEFI systems will read FAT32, usually also ISO9660, some will read NTFS too) and the partition has `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI`. If such a file does not exist, then that partition is not bootable without additional configuration, as far as the UEFI firmware is concerned.

`startup.nsh` is not a bootloader. It is a start-up script file for EFI shell.

An EFI shell is sort of halfway in functionality between a Linux `busybox` shell and a Windows `cmd.exe` command prompt... but it can run on top of UEFI firmware: it does not need any OS kernel. It is usually named `shell.efi` but can be renamed to `<anything>.efi`, or can be an embedded feature in some UEFI firmware implementations.

`startup.nsh` can only run `*.efi` files, other `*.nsh` scripts and internal commands of the EFI shell.

I downloaded the [home edition of CloudReady](https://www.neverware.com/freedownload#home-edition-install). It's available as a Windows .exe or a .zip file that contains a .bin disk image, so I don't know what you are talking about an ISO. But the disk image file has a hybrid MBR/GPT partition table: when interpreted as MBR it shows just two partitions, but interpreted as GPT, it has a whopping 27 partitions!

An old computer that clearly has UEFI (since GRUB's `fwsetup` works) might have an early version of UEFI firmware that may not have been tested with such complicated set-ups, and as a result, UEFI firmware bugs might prevent booting a CloudReady USB stick. Try with something simpler first.

In the GRUB prompt, type `set` and press Enter. It should output several lines of text. Are there lines that start with `prefix=` or `root=`? What do they say exactly? If there's so much text it scrolls off the screen, type `set pager=1`, press Enter, then `set` and Enter again. Now it should pause between screenfuls of text.

If any command results in an error message, please copy it *exactly* and edit the command and the error message into your question. You might not know what it means, but someone here will.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I was dumb and didn't know Cloudready was a bin instead of an ISO. I tried Lubuntu again and it installed fine. I really appreciate the help since I can finally use the computer again.